# How to implement multiple filters on model's array/content via checkbox

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to implement multiple filters on the same model. The attributes I want to apply the filter are arrays.

```
//Exam Model
App.Exam = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    description: DS.attr('string'),
    courses : DS.hasMany('course',{ async: true }),

});

//Course Model
App.Course = DS.Model.extend({
 name: DS.attr('string'),
  description:DS.attr('string'),
  professors: DS.attr(),
  subjects: DS.attr(),
  languages: DS.attr(),
    exam: DS.belongsTo('exam', { async: true })
});
```

In the `ExamsExam` route after the model is resloved I extract the data I want to apply the filter on.

```
App.ExamsExamRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {

    return this.store.find('exam', params.exam_id).then(function (exam) {
        console.log("found single exam", exam);
            return exam;
        });
  },

  afterModel: function(model, transition){
    var self = this;
    var professorList = [];
    var subjectList = [];
    var languageList = [];

    var promise = new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        var courses = model.get('courses');

        courses.forEach(function(course){
          self.store.find('course', course.get('id')).then(function(course){
            var profs = course.get('professors');
            var subjects = course.get('subjects');
            var languages = course.get('languages');

            profs.forEach(function(prof) {
              if (professorList.indexOf(prof) === -1) {
                professorList.pushObject(prof);
              }
            });

            subjects.forEach(function(subject) {
              if (subjectList.indexOf(subject)  === -1) {
                subjectList.pushObject(subject);
              }
            });

            languages.forEach(function(language) {
              if (languageList.indexOf(language)  === -1) {
                languageList.pushObject(language);
              }
            });
          });
        });
        var data = {
          professorList: professorList,
          subjectList: subjectList,
          languageList: languageList
        };
        resolve(data);
    });

    promise.then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      model.set('professorNameList', data.professorList);
      model.set('subjectList', data.subjectList);
      model.set('languageList', data.languageList);
    });
  }
});
```

And this is my template

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="exams/exam">
  <h2>Exam page</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 well">
       <ul class="list-group well">
        {{#each course in model.languageList}}
         <li class="">
           <label>
            {{input type='checkbox'}}
            {{course}}
          </label>
        </li>
      {{/each}}
      </ul>

      <ul class="list-group well">
        {{#each prof in model.professorNameList}}
         <li class="">
           <label>
            {{input type='checkbox'}}
            {{prof}}
          </label>
        </li>
      {{/each}}
      </ul>


      <ul class="list-group well">
        {{#each subject in model.subjectList}}
         <li class="">
           <label>
            {{input type='checkbox'}}
            {{subject}}
          </label>
        </li>
      {{/each}}
      </ul>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-9">
      {{#each course in model.courses}}
        <div class="well">
          Course name - {{course.name}}<br>
          Professors - {{course.professors}}<br>
          Subjects - {{course.subjects}}
        </div>
      {{/each}}
    </div>
  </div>

  </script>
```

Now how do I change the content of the model so that if a user selects the language filter, only the courses belong to that selected language must be displayed.
Plus if the user selects language and subjects filter, only the filters matching that criteria should be displayed.

There is very little documentation on filtering via checkbox in ember.

Someone please suggest/guide me on how to approach this problem and get a clean solution.

Here is the [JS BIN DEMO](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cusolo/1/edit?html,js,output) for better illustration of what I want to achieve.

Comment: Pretty sure `store.filter` is what you're looking for http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_filter . Your example is a a little tricky because you want to filter courses based on languages, but you get the languages from the course model?

Comment: Yea basically the course model has an array of languages that the course belongs to. Similarly it also has a professors array and subjects array that the course belongs to. I am not sure how to filter it based on multiple parameters. I have found a solution if it is a single array filter but not for multiple arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on @joostdevries's answer...

Using `every()` with a callback is a fine solution, but it "feels" a little complicated. What you are looking for is basically an intersect between the arrays. For example, common professors to both an array of selected professors and array of professors in the model. Ember provides just such function, called ... wait for it ... `intersection` (see [here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.EnumerableUtils.html#method_intersection)) :). It returns an array containing the elements common to both arrays or an empty (0 length) array if there are no common elements.

Here is the same `filteredCourses` property, using the `intersection` method.

```
filteredCourses: function() {
  var selectedProfessors = this.get('selectedProfessors'),
      selectedLanguages = this.get('selectedLanguages'),
      selectedSubjects = this.get('selectedSubjects'),
      courses = this.get('model.courses');

  var intersectFn = Ember.EnumerableUtils.intersection;

  return courses.filter(function(course) {
    return intersectFn(course.get('professors') || [], selectedProfessors).length ||
           intersectFn(course.get('languages') || [], selectedLanguages).length ||
           intersectFn(course.get('subjects') || [], selectedSubjects).length;
  });
}.property('selectedProfessors.length', 'selectedLanguages.length', 'selectedSubjects.length')
```

First, we alias the intersection function as follows:

`var intersectFn = Ember.EnumerableUtils.intersection;`

This step is purely cosmetic - I just don't feel like typing `Ember.EnumerableUtils.intersection` every time; instead I just want to type `intersectFn`. Then, I just use the function to see if the arrays intersect. If they do - the `length` of resulting array would be greater than 0, which evaluates to true; otherwise - the length is 0, which evaluates to false. The one last quirk in all of this is that sometimes the property will be `undefined` which messes up the `intersection` method. For such cases, I set the array to empty.

So, `course.get('professors') || []` means, if professors property (array) is defined - use it; otherwise - use an empty array.

Working solution [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qoturu/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Great solution. Though I made few changes to it. Thanks again. People who are stuck with the same scenario will find it useful.

Comment: Thanx, I ended up putting in a pull request https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/10296 to avoid the `|| []` We'll see if ember team feels it's useful

Answer (score 2):

With [`store.filter`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_filter), you have a callback function which returns a boolean that decides whether or not something matches the filter:

```
filteredCourses: function() {
    return courses.filter(function(course) {
      return selectedProfessors.every(function(prof) {
        return course.get('professors').contains(prof);
      }) &&  selectedLanguages.every(function(lang) {
        return course.get('languages').contains(lang);
      }) && selectedSubjects.every(function(subj) {
        return course.get('subjects').contains(subj);
      });
    });
}.property()
```

Here's an updated JSBin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/comosepuno/1/. The checkbox component is borrowed from https://github.com/RSSchermer/ember-multiselect-checkboxes

Comment: Not getting where do I put this code :( And how do I send the selected profs or subjects or languages to this function ?

Comment: Yes thanks. I will check it once its updated and try to understand how to do it.

Comment: If you find time, please can you help me out with the js bin ?

Comment: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/comosepuno/1/ I borrowed some code from https://github.com/RSSchermer/ember-multiselect-checkboxes . Was really busy so I only just got around to it.

Comment: Hi checked the fiddle, I kinda got the idea. But one more thing, in your fiddle, If I select languages - Hindi and English I get no results. Typically it should search for courses which have Hindi or English as languages right? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Ajey That's up to you. You can easily modify the `filteredCourses` function to do an "OR" match instead of an "AND" match. I hope I've given you enough material to work with.

Comment: @joostdevries - great solution! I upvoted and provided a slight variation myself